# Does Treeview use command bindings for expand/collapse?

Tags: wpf, treeview, keyboard-shortcuts, commandbinding

The WPF Treeview responds to <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> keystrokes to expand and collapse nodes in the tree.  Great!

Is there an existing command I can bind my toolbar buttons or menu items to to perform the same actions in the treeview?  I don't see anything related to expand/collapse in the stock command constants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TreeView` handles the expansion of a `TreeViewItem` with the mouse by binding `ToggleButton.IsChecked` to `TreeViewItem.IsExpanded` in the `ControlTemplate` and handles expansion with the keyboard in an override `TreeViewItem.OnKeyDown`.  So, no, it doesn't use commands in its implementation.

But you can add your own commands without much effort.  In this example, I've added a behavior to a `TreeView` so that it responds to the standard `Open` and `Close` application commands:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="Open" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=treeView1}" Command="Open"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Close" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=treeView1}" Command="Close"/>
    </Menu>
    <TreeView>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:TreeViewCommandsBehavior/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Root">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Item1">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem1"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem2"/>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Item2">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem3"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Subitem4"/>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</DockPanel>
```

and here is the behavior that makes that work:

```
public class TreeViewCommandsBehavior : Behavior<TreeView>
{
    private TreeViewItem selectedTreeViewItem;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.AddHandler(TreeViewItem.SelectedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(TreeViewItem_Selected));
        AssociatedObject.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Open, CommandExecuted));
        AssociatedObject.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Close, CommandExecuted));
    }

    private void TreeViewItem_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedTreeViewItem = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
    }

    private void CommandExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool expand = e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Open;
        if (selectedTreeViewItem != null)
            selectedTreeViewItem.IsExpanded = expand;
    }
}
```

If you are not familiar with behaviors, first add this namespace:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

and add the corresponding reference to your project.

Comment: Note that the System.Windows.Interactivity assembly is not part of the .NET 4.0 runtime distribution; it's available in the Microsoft Expression Blend SDK redistributables.

Comment: Somehow, that fact had eluded me, probably because the name of the assembly.  Although it creates a dependency on an external assembly, using behaviors is a big win because it makes the feature reusable without involving any code-behind.  Thanks for pointing that out.