# System.Windows.Interactivity: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

I am trying to reference System.Windows.Interactivity in order to [support IsExpanded behavior command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731718/does-treeview-use-command-bindings-for-expand-collapse)

But as soon as i add a reference to this assembly, i get the error loading System.Windows 2.0. This appears to be a known bug, and solution appears to be to just reference that assembly.

I downloaded Silverlight SDK, and referenced assembly in question in my project.

however, now i am getting lots of conflicts between System.Windows, and WindowsBase.dll. Classes such as RoutedEventHandler exist in both.. Must be a way to fix this, since i see people being successful in using that Interactivity dll with wpf 4.0..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have a WPF project you need to use the WPF specific version of that assembly, maybe you took the wrong .dll?

Here are the two respective file paths on my system:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0\Libraries\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll
```

Comment: my Expression dir only has /Silverlight in it.. so i took the Interactivity.dll from there. System.Windows was not there at all, so i got that by installing silverlight sdk, and then get it from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0

Comment: @SonicSoul: You **cannot** use Silverlight libraries in WPF don't even try. If the WPF assembly is not there then reinstall the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=f1ae9a30-4928-411d-970b-e682ab179e17&displaylang=en) and make sure that the WPF components will be installed.

Comment: i got System.Windows.Interactivity.dll from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries

Comment: @SonicSoul: As i said, that is for Silverlight, it **cannot** be used in WPF

Comment: where else could i get System.Windows.Interactivity?

Comment: @SonicSoul: Also as i said, reinstall the Blend SDK (link in recent comment) and see if you can get it to install the WPF component.

Comment: @SonicSoul: Newer version [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10801)...

Comment: thanks! sorry i responded before seeing all of your comments. i'll give that a try

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference the dll's in the main project (not just the control libraries).  It was the problem in my case.  See more info here:
[Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Interactivity'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514027/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-windows-interactivity)

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when running a project built in a previous version of Visual Studio, but I was running it in VS2017.

My issue was resolved by opening the VS2017 installer and modifying my install to select the **"Blend for Visual Studio SDK for .Net"** component in the VS 2017 install.

[image: Screenshot of VS2017 installer window showing component to select]

Fissh

Answer (score 1):

If one of your projects is targeting the .NET 4.0 Client Profile you might find switching to the full .NET 4.0 framework corrects the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sonic, like H.B. said you can't use Silverlight version in WPF.  You will need to install different [WPF specific Expression Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=10801) instead of Silverlight.