# An error in handling event. MVVM

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, listbox, event-handling

I am using Visual Studio 2010 SP1. I've met a lot of articles where describes code of event handling(see below). For example [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18199.event-handling-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application.aspx) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030417/mvvm-view-event-viewmodel-command-binding).

I've added an assembly `System.Windows.Interactivity`. I am using `ICommand` interface to handle Commands. However, when I write a property "Command" in the line:

```
   <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"/>
```

**I catch an error:** **Property `"Command"` does not exist in namespace XML "clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity".**.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeData}" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10" Background="LightGreen">            
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction CommandName="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding YourCommandParameter}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>            
</ListBox>
```

Thus I have two questions:

1. Where can I get a property `Command`? Or what should I write instead of it? I've tried to write `CommandName` but I've caught an error.
2. What should I write to `CommandParameter` property? What type of a property should I create in a viewmodel to bind it to `CommandParameter`?

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party framework?

Comment: You need to define a class which implements `ICommand` interface. You can check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468791/wpf-icommand-mvvm-implementation) which might help you understand `Command`

Comment: What is your i namespace?

Comment: @aks81 yeah, I am using ICommand.

Comment: It's weired because it compiles  and runs on my computer with no error and I don't even have a VM behind just copied your code. You have Blend SDK 4.0 installed?

Comment: Control Panel -> Installed programs -> searchif you have Microsoft Expression Blend SDK 4

Comment: The only explanation I see is that you actually referenced the Blend SDK 3. I checked it and yep it don't have Command property in that version.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51262/discussion-between-stepup-and-didier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we talked in the WPF chat room, take a look in the following question, it is quite similar to your problem.

[Properties does not exist : System.Windows.Interactivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575411/properties-does-not-exist-system-windows-interactivity)